# Is there any way to tell Storm Nimbus to start a topology in particular supervisor?

Tags: load-balancing, apache-storm, nimbus

I have a storm cluster (1.0.2 version) set up and 5 topologies are up and running in it. Among 2 of them are cpu intensive and memory intensive topologies. While submitting topologies, i want those 2 processor should run in separate supervisors in storm nimbus cluster. So that the load and resources will be shared. But whenever i stop and restart the topology, 99% of the time those 2 cpu and memory intensive processors are running in same supervisors. So one supervisor cpu usage goes upto 95% and even sometimes burst as cpu usage reaches 100%. Is there any way to make those 2 processor to run in separate supervisors always?.

Comment: How many supervisors have you configured ?

Comment: Hi Dani, i have configured 3 supervisors.

Comment: I guess this is what was done here: https://inside.edited.com/taking-control-of-your-apache-storm-cluster-with-tag-aware-scheduling-b60aaaa5e37e

Answer (score 1):

I sounds to me like a resource-aware-scheduler (RAS) could solve your problem. Using a RAS, it should be possible to make sure that each topology is deployed on a separate supervisor.

See: [storm official documentation](https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/Resource_Aware_Scheduler_overview.html)